# Create two disks for multiple environment machines in Vagrant

Tags: ruby, virtual-machine, vagrant, virtualbox, vagrantfile

I'm going to create a multiple environments machines with Vagrant. Here is the VagrantFile I'm trying to configure. I would like to instantiate seven machines connected them across a private networks. Every of this one should have two disks.  I have found in Vagrant documentation the VBoxManage that expose the `createhd` command. I'm not sure where should I place this command. Inside every machine block or inside virtual provider block config?

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|

    config.vm.provision "shell", inline: "echo OpenStack"

    config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"

    config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
        vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", "2048", "--cpus", "1"]
    end

    config.vm.define "machine1" do |machine1|

        machine1.vm.hostname = "machine1"

        machine1.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
            vb.customize ["createhd",  "--filename", "machine1_disk0", "--size", "4096"]
            vb.customize ["createhd",  "--filename", "machine1_disk1", "--size", "4096"]
            vb.customize ["storagectl", :id, "--name", "SATA Controller", "--add", "sata"]
            vb.customize ["storageattach", :id, "--storagectl", "SATA Controller", "--port", "1", "--type", "hdd", "--medium", "machine1_disk0.vdi"]
            vb.customize ["storageattach", :id, "--storagectl", "SATA Controller", "--port", "2", "--type", "hdd", "--medium", "machine1_disk1.vdi"]
        end

        machine1.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.10.10"
        machine1.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.10.15"
    end

    config.vm.define "machine2" do |machine2|

        machine2.vm.hostname = "machine2"

        machine2.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
            vb.customize ["createhd",  "--filename", "machine2_disk0", "--size", "4096"]
            vb.customize ["createhd",  "--filename", "machine2_disk1", "--size", "4096"]
            vb.customize ["storagectl", :id, "--name", "SATA Controller", "--add", "sata"]
            vb.customize ["storageattach", :id, "--storagectl", "SATA Controller", "--port", "1", "--type", "hdd", "--medium", "machine2_disk0.vdi"]
            vb.customize ["storageattach", :id, "--storagectl", "SATA Controller", "--port", "2", "--type", "hdd", "--medium", "machine2_disk1.vdi"]
        end

        machine2.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.10.20"
        machine2.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.10.25"
    end

    config.vm.define "machine3" do |machine3|

        machine3.vm.hostname = "machine3"

        machine3.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
            vb.customize ["createhd",  "--filename", "machine3_disk0", "--size", "4096"]
            vb.customize ["createhd",  "--filename", "machine3_disk1", "--size", "4096"]
            vb.customize ["storagectl", :id, "--name", "SATA Controller", "--add", "sata"]
            vb.customize ["storageattach", :id, "--storagectl", "SATA Controller", "--port", "1", "--type", "hdd", "--medium", "machine3_disk0.vdi"]
            vb.customize ["storageattach", :id, "--storagectl", "SATA Controller", "--port", "2", "--type", "hdd", "--medium", "machine3_disk1.vdi"]
        end

        machine3.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.10.30"
    end

    config.vm.define "machine4" do |machine4|

        machine4.vm.hostname = "machine4"

        machine4.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
            vb.customize ["createhd",  "--filename", "machine4_disk0", "--size", "4096"]
            vb.customize ["createhd",  "--filename", "machine4_disk1", "--size", "4096"]
            vb.customize ["storagectl", :id, "--name", "SATA Controller", "--add", "sata"]
            vb.customize ["storageattach", :id, "--storagectl", "SATA Controller", "--port", "1", "--type", "hdd", "--medium", "machine4_disk0.vdi"]
            vb.customize ["storageattach", :id, "--storagectl", "SATA Controller", "--port", "2", "--type", "hdd", "--medium", "machine4_disk1.vdi"]
        end

        machine4.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.10.40"
    end

    config.vm.define "machine5" do |machine5|

        machine5.vm.hostname = "machine5"

        machine5.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
            vb.customize ["createhd",  "--filename", "machine5_disk0", "--size", "4096"]
            vb.customize ["createhd",  "--filename", "machine5_disk1", "--size", "4096"]
            vb.customize ["storagectl", :id, "--name", "SATA Controller", "--add", "sata"]
            vb.customize ["storageattach", :id, "--storagectl", "SATA Controller", "--port", "1", "--type", "hdd", "--medium", "machine5_disk0.vdi"]
            vb.customize ["storageattach", :id, "--storagectl", "SATA Controller", "--port", "2", "--type", "hdd", "--medium", "machine5_disk1.vdi"]
        end

        machine5.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.10.50"
    end

    config.vm.define "machine6" do |machine6|

        machine6.vm.hostname = "machine6"

        machine6.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
            vb.customize ["createhd",  "--filename", "machine6_disk0", "--size", "4096"]
            vb.customize ["createhd",  "--filename", "machine6_disk1", "--size", "4096"]
            vb.customize ["storagectl", :id, "--name", "SATA Controller", "--add", "sata"]
            vb.customize ["storageattach", :id, "--storagectl", "SATA Controller", "--port", "1", "--type", "hdd", "--medium", "machine6_disk0.vdi"]
            vb.customize ["storageattach", :id, "--storagectl", "SATA Controller", "--port", "2", "--type", "hdd", "--medium", "machine6_disk1.vdi"]
        end

        machine6.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.10.60"
    end

    config.vm.define "machine7" do |machine7|

        machine7.vm.hostname = "machine7"

        machine7.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
            vb.customize ["createhd",  "--filename", "machine7_disk0", "--size", "4096"]
            vb.customize ["createhd",  "--filename", "machine7_disk1", "--size", "4096"]
            vb.customize ["storagectl", :id, "--name", "SATA Controller", "--add", "sata"]
            vb.customize ["storageattach", :id, "--storagectl", "SATA Controller", "--port", "1", "--type", "hdd", "--medium", "machine7_disk0.vdi"]
            vb.customize ["storageattach", :id, "--storagectl", "SATA Controller", "--port", "2", "--type", "hdd", "--medium", "machine7_disk1.vdi"]
        end

        machine7.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.10.70"
    end
```

end

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all customizations, like `createhd`, must be added to provider. 
If you add it to config provider

```
config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
   config.vm.customize ['createhd', '--filename', file_to_disk, '--size', some_size]
   config.vm.customize ['storageattach', :id, '--storagectl', 'SATA Controller', '--port', 1, '--device', 0, '--type', 'hdd', '--medium', file_to_disk] 
end
```

It will be defined globally, and these parameters will be used by all machines. *(Not sure)* In result only one disk will be created, and will be shared among defined machines.

I think you should define provider in each machine. E.g

```
config.vm.define "machine4" do |machine4|
    machine4.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.10.40"
    machine4.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
        vb.customize ["createhd",  "--filename", "m4_disk0", "--size", "2048"]
        vb.customize ["storageattach", :id, "--storagectl", "SATA Controller", "--port", "1", "--type", "hdd", "--medium", "m4_disk0.vdi"]

    end
end
```

Please  treat this [Vagrantfile](https://gitlab.msu.edu/gmason/vagrant-zfs/blob/master/Vagrantfile) as a reference.

Comment: I have tried to create the config file but I got some issues about the storage controller. how much controllers should I create? Edited the config file

Comment: I get this error:  VBoxManage: error: Too many storage controllers of this type

Answer (score 5):

Well, you really want it to create and attach the extra storage just once.  I believe the accepted answer above will cause an error on subsequent runs because the .VDI file is already created (*and* already attached).

The way to do this is to test if the VDI file is on the host's disk with `File.exist?`, meaning it's already been created.

For multi-machines, this might be what you want:

```
(1..3).each do |i|
    config.vm.define "node-#{i}" do |node|
        node.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.200.#{i}"
        file_for_disk = "./large_disk#{i}.vdi"
        node.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
           unless File.exist?(file_for_disk)
               v.customize ['createhd', 
                            '--filename', file_for_disk, 
                            '--size', 80 * 1024]
               v.customize ['storageattach', :id, 
                            '--storagectl', 'SATAController', 
                            '--port', 1, '--device', 0, '--type', 'hdd', '--medium', file_for_disk]
           end
       end
   end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

'This works for me.'
'I thought I share this as it might help Vagrant Newbie like me.'

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
file_to_disk = '../second_disk.vdi'
# create CrushFTP nodes
   (1..2).each do |i|
     config.vm.define "cftpnode#{i}" do |node|
         node.vm.customize ['createhd', '--filename', file_to_disk, '--size', 500 * 1024]
         node.vm.customize ['storageattach', :id, '--storagectl', 'SATA Controller', '--port', 1, '--device', 0, '--type', 'hdd', '--medium', file_to_disk] 
         node.vm.box = "bento/centos-7.2"
         node.vm.hostname = "cftpnode#{i}"
         node.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.0.1#{i}"
         node.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
             vb.memory = "1024"
                     end
       node.vm.provision :shell, path: "bootstrap-node.sh"
   end
  end
end
```