# Vagrant: Place extra diskimage along with rest of virtual machine

Tags: ubuntu, vagrant, virtualbox

I have a situation where my bento/ubuntu-14.04 image is too small for some integration tests.  Therefore I would like to increase its size, and I have found how to do so at https://stackoverflow.com/a/27878224/53897 using

```
  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
    v.memory = 8192
    v.cpus = 2 # or more for heavy load
    # https://stackoverflow.com/a/27878224/53897
    v.customize ["createhd",  "--filename", "m4_disk0", "--size", "1048576"] # 1 TB
    v.customize ["storageattach", :id, "--storagectl", "SATA Controller", "--port", "1", "--type", "hdd", "--medium", "m4_disk0.vdi"]
  end
```

which is then later added with

```
# First add the extra disk and extend the root volume.
#
# Adapted from https://www.rootusers.com/how-to-increase-the-size-of-a-linux-lvm-by-adding-a-new-disk/

fdisk /dev/sdb << EOF
n
p
1


t
8e
w
EOF

pvcreate /dev/sdb1
vgextend vagrant-vg /dev/sdb1
lvextend -r /dev/vagrant-vg/root /dev/sdb1

# ---
```

This seem to work very nicely, and is cleaned properly when doing "vagrant destroy".  (We do not restart the vagrant instance, just suspend it manually).

Now I have the problem that the "m4_disk0.vdi" file is created next to my `Vagrantfile` instead of along with the rest of the VirtualBox files which is rather inconvenient as my sources are on a fast but small SSD and the VirtualBox files are on a large but slower HDD.

Is there a reliable way to ask Vagrant where VirtualBox put the instance so I can use it to create a suitable filename there?

My host runs Ubuntu 17.04 which comes with Vagrant 1.9.1.

Answer (score 2):

vagrant runs the command in the same folder as your Vagrantfile so the file is created there, if you want to indicate another directory change it

```
v.customize ["createhd",  "--filename", "/path/to/file/m4_disk0.vdi", "--size", "1048576"] # 1 TB
v.customize ["storageattach", :id, "--storagectl", "SATA Controller", "--port", "1", "--type", "hdd", "--medium", "/path/to/file/m4_disk0.vdi"]
```

Those are virtualbox command run on behalf of vagrant, so the information about the location of the files will be kept in the vbox file

## Get the location of current configuration

vagrant will store the VM id in a file under `.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/id` (if you change the name of your VM in vagrant the default folder might change)

as Vagrantfile is a ruby script you can run your ruby command, something like this

```
id = File.read(".vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/id")
location = `vboxmanage showvminfo #{id} -machinereadable | grep CfgFile`.chomp().scan(/"(.*)"/).first().first()
```

location will hold the location of the initial vbox file, so you still need to strip off this name to get the folder location and then you will be able to indicate this folder when you create the new hard drive.

I am not a ruby guru so there might be better ways to write all this (potentially using regex finding all elements till last `/` or something but the main vagrant idea is this one)

Comment: You misunderstand.  I would like to NOT hardcode the path but explicitly inquire vagrant where they are and then construct a path next to that.

Comment: so you want to read the results of `vboxmanage showvminfo <your vm id> --machinereadable | grep CfgFile` and put the file in this folder ?

Comment: Essentially yes.   Can I ask Vagrant about my vm id?

Comment: you can. it will be under `.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/id` if you did not change the name of the VM machine (default in my example, else you'll need to change accordingly). edit the answer with some code to read and try to read the right location

Comment: Initial experiments indicate that the "id" file does not exist when I try to execute my code.  The `:id` identifier might still be useful though.  I have asked on the vagrant mailing list too, just to hear how they would suggest to do this.  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vagrant-up/A4x61yxsOIU

Comment: hum the id file is there for sure, under the `.vagrant` directory of your project (next to your Vagrantfile) you will have the full path to the `id` file, normally its `.vagrant/machines/<machine_name>/<provider>/id` along with id, you will have `index_uui`, `private_key` and so on

Comment: Yes, but apparently not yet when starting from scratch at the time the steps in the vagrant file are executed.  At least that is what I gather from the error message.  The VM has not been renamed.

Comment: oh right, the Vagrantfile is fully read before anything gets executed - in the case I did, the VM was created so I had results. sorry about that. so basically from Vagrantfile you cannot get this info. it would need to be done during the vagrant execution, so through a plugin

Comment: Thanks.  That explains why apparently nobody has been able to do this well yet.